# Is there a way to load test every component of an AWS solution using Distributed Load Testing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance-testing, load-testing

Is there a way to load test every component of an AWS solution using Distributed Load Testing? https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/

I have an AWS serverless ecommerce solution, which has a step function(which has a few lambda functions), an API gateway and RDS. I want to load test the solution at different endpoints like load the step function, then load the API gateway so on and so forth.
So, I've deployed https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/ and I am facing 2 issues:

1. To test the entire solution I have the target URL for the S3 bucket that is the entry point to the solution, now the problem is that the authentication key and password are cycled every week. So, I have to keep updating script with the latest key id and password. Is there a way for me to use some other mechanism like have a jenkins authorised user and integrate it with the distributed load testing(DLT) solution OR some other way to keep the entire process automated without compromising the security?
2. Secondly, I have to load test endpoints that do not have external URLs like the step function (there is an async lambda that initiates the step function) and in order to send payload to the step function through DLT I need a target URL. Is it even possible to load test in such a scenario? If yes, how? I have tried using serverless artillery but again it needs a target URL.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Load Testing**

So if I understand your question correctly, you're looking for ways to load-test your AWS setup. Well you're using serverless technologies which are scalable by default. So if you load-test the environment, most probably you'll reach the service limits depending on the load you generate. All these limits are already documented well in AWS documentation.

Load testing only makes sense (to me) when you're using EC2 instances (or Fargate) and want to know how many instances you need for particular load. Or how much time it takes for system scaling to work.

**Database**

To load test your RDS you don't have to load test all the components of your setup. You can independently load test it using JMeter or any other tool.

**Other Consideration**

If you're going with distributed Load testing then you have to notify AWS beforehand. Your distributed load might trigger few DDoS like alarms in AWS.